# How will I derive Json objects from JS array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have this Json file located in different folder than my js file:

```
{"Title":"test1", "content":"test2"}, {"Title":"test1", "content":"test2"}
```

I want to read this file and turn the json into a JavaScript array of objects.

I can use jQuery.

Comment: What should the array look like?

Comment: It is an array which I want to load it through AJAX, I want to re-create this array of objects and display the first one along with a <input type=hidden…> field.

Comment: Are you saying you want to load the json from the external json file into a JS array?  Can you use jQuery?

Comment: Well, it doesn't help it if you say "It is an array". What kind of arary? What elements of the object do you want in the array?

Comment: Does it start as JSON or JavaScript array?

Comment: Hi Gordon, Yes I can use jquery. I want to be able to load them separately from JS to different html <div> but not as a list.

Comment: So, are you trying to read JSON from file and transform it into an array of objects?

Comment: yes that is what i am trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go: **http://jsfiddle.net/p3p5P/**

Use **[jQuery.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)** to load JSON-encoded data from the server using a GET HTTP request.  Then use **[jQuery.parseJSON](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)** to takes a well-formed JSON string and return the resulting JavaScript object.

```
//$.getJSON("yourJsonFile.json", function(myJson) {
    //console.log(json); // this will show the info in the console

    //hard-code the json for this fiddle example, you will load it with the getJSON statement above
    var myJson    = '[{"Title":"title1","content":"content1"},{"Title":"title2","content":"content2"}]';

    var myJsonObj = $.parseJSON(myJson);
    console.log(myJsonObj); //you now have an array of objects.
    alert(myJsonObj[0].Title); //how to reference the first title
    alert(myJsonObj[1].Title); //how to reference the second title
    alert(myJsonObj[0].content); //how to reference the first content
    alert(myJsonObj[1].content); //how to reference the second content
//});
```

NOTE: In this example I turned your json data into an array by enclosing the entire string within [ ].  So you will want to edit your json and change this...

```
{"Title":"title1","content":"content1"},{"Title":"title2","content":"content2"}
```

into this...

```
[{"Title":"title1","content":"content1"},{"Title":"title2","content":"content2"}]
```

Comment: @user2976554 I see you are new to stackoverflow and have never marked any of your questions as answered.  If this answers your question then please click the "checkmark" next to it.  And you could go back through your previous questions and do the same.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use [jQuery.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) to get Json from file,
and then use [jQuery.parseJSON](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) to transform into a JS array.

```
$.getJSON( "ajax/test.json", function( data ) {
    var jsarray = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
});
```